# Webapp2 Routing and Python inclusion

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2, webapp2

In the webapp2 URI routing there are some examples using `webapp2.Route(r'/', handler='...')`, and some aren't using r'/' -- so my question is, what is the R for, and should I be using it?

Also, if you use webapp2_extras.APIs you need to pass the config to the WSGIApplication(), is it possible to define the config lists elsewhere?

As in, is it possible to do `config['webapp2_extras.API'] = ['option':'value']` in one file, then include that file inside your "router" and use the variable/list

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score -1):

Copied Here from Comment:

It defines a raw string. Please read docs docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals paying special attention to raw strings. You may use a raw string to more easily define a regular expression as a literal string.

Comment: r'..' does not indicate a regular expression.  It defines a raw string.  Please read docs http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals paying special attention to raw strings. You may use a raw string to more easily define a regular expression as a literal string.